# Access to inexistent member don't give type error

Tags: angular, typescript

The Angular's Docs says that if you access a nonexistent member it should give a compile error, and the function **$any()** should solve

```
<!-- Accessing an undeclared member -->
  <div>
    The hero's marker is {{$any(hero).marker}}
  </div>
```

In my case, writing in the interpolation only **hero.market** does not return an error, and I wanted to ask you if it was normal and happen to you too, or is just the my special typescript/angular compiler.

Comment: when you put "any" make that you have NOT error. {{hero.marker}} give you an error {{hero?.marker}} dont give you an error but not show anything

Comment: This is the problem, {{hero.marker}} don't give me error.